# angular.copy removes frunctions from JS objects. Any alternatives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some js variables saved as:

```
{
            "column": {
                "stacking": 'normal',
                "dataLabels": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "color": 'white',
                    "formatter": function() {
                        if (this.y != 0) {
                            return this.y + '%';
                        } else {
                            return null;
                        }
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "textShadow": '0 0 2px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Inside an angular controller when I copy this variable using angular.copy(varName), the **formatter** function gets removed.

Most probably angular.copy doesn't work well with functions. What are other alternatives?

I need to change the **varName** attributes and values and it binds if I do it multiple times in the same controller.

jQuery.extend(true, {}, varName) does the same

EDIT:
I was wrong, angular.copy works fine.
My mistake is that I was doing a JSON.stringify and JSON.parse for the object and there function was removed.

Comment: lodash.clone maybe?

Comment: I tried this and it's working : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29060/

Comment: yes, you're right. Then I'm wrong with my code. Thanks.

Comment: `angular.copy` works fine with function, may be you are doing other mistake.

Comment: true, I've updated the question

Comment: I'm voting to close the question as "No Longer Reproducible";  in it's current state, it's not **obvious** that the problem doesn't exist, and people may continue to attempt to offer answers, which shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

No, `angular.copy` doesn't remove functions.

```js
var obj = {
  "column": {
    "stacking": 'normal',
    "dataLabels": {
      "enabled": true,
      "color": 'white',
      "formatter": function() {
        if (this.y != 0) {
          return this.y + '%';
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
      "style": {
        "textShadow": '0 0 2px black'
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(angular.copy(obj))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One case where `angular.copy` wouldn't copy your `formatter` property is when the `formatter`'s **enumerable property descriptor** is set to `false`.

You can try this out like this:

```
var yourObj = {
  "column": {
    "stacking": 'normal',
    "dataLabels": {
      "enabled": true,
      "color": 'white',
      "formatter": function() {
        if (this.y != 0) {
          return this.y + '%';
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
      "style": {
        "textShadow": '0 0 2px black'
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(angular.copy(yourObj)); //formatter property is there.

Object.defineProperty(yourObj, "formatter", {
  value: function() {
        if (this.y != 0) {
          return this.y + '%';
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
  enumerable: false,
  writable: true,
  configurable: true
});

console.log(angular.copy(yourObj)); //formatter property is not there.
```

If you haven't modified property descriptors for the `formatter` property, `angular.copy` should work.